# bootstrap-datepicker-rails set default century view to 20th century

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using the [bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-datepicker-rails) and have the following code to show the date picker in my rails app:

```
<%= text_field_tag :birth_date, params[:birth_date], size: 9, data: {provide: 'datepicker', date_start_view: 'decades'}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Here is what it shows when the user clicks on the date picker:

[image: First View from Datepicker]

As one can see: by setting the option of `data: {date_start_view: 'decades'}`: the date picker defaults to the 21st century (2000 - 2100).  I want it to default to the 20th century because this date picker is for a birthdate.

I did look through the [bootstrap-datepicker documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but it was unclear to me how to set this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the last century decades you may consider [the following option reported in the documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#defaultviewdate):

> ***defaultViewDate***
>
> Date to view when initially opening the calendar. The internal value of the date remains today as default, but when the datepicker is first opened the calendar will open to defaultViewDate rather than today. If this option is not used, “today” remains the default view date.

Therefore, you must change the ***defaultViewDate*** from today to a date belonging to the last century.

That means you must change the following section reported in your code :

```
data: {provide: 'datepicker', date_start_view: 'decades'}
```

to:

```
data: {provide="datepicker", date_default_view_date="01/01/1900", date_start_view="decades"}
```

In the following an example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/master/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/master/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-default-view-date="01/01/1900" data-date-start-view="decades">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was not able to get `date_default_view_date` to work as described here, but I was able to get it working using `date_default_view_date: {year: 1900, month: 0, day: 1}`.

Comment: @moveson Thanks for the comment. As you can see by yourself defaultViewDate as [An object with keys year, month and day (can’t be set from a data attribute)](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#defaultviewdate). A way to apply the object data is: **$('[data-provide="datepicker"]').datepicker({defaultViewDate: {year: 1900, month: 0, day: 1}});** In any case, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Using options from [bootstrap-datepicker sandbox](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?#sandbox)

A defined in [Using bootstrap-datepicker-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails/#using-bootstrap-datepicker-rails) you can use this configuration

this demo is on js and html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: "01/01/1900",
    endDate: "12/31/1999",// you may omit
    startView: 3,
    maxViewMode: 3
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<input type="text" class='datepicker' >
```