# How to set date range 2 decade before and year as default view in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have requirement to set bootstrap date picker default view as year and it must be 2000-2009.In that I can select date up to current year.
Default view must be like below image.

I tried   startView: 2,  but it go only one decade back.

Comment: `User1710` Where is the image

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812143/bootstrap-datepicker-rails-set-default-century-view-to-20th-century